# Searching Files with sequence number in a specific order in C#

Tags: c#, itext

I have a folder that contains more than 200K images. 
Some images will follow the below pattern of file names:

```
5093_1.jpg
5093_2.jpg
5093_3.jpg
5093_4.jpg
5093_5.jpg
5094_1.jpg
5094_2.jpg
5094_3.jpg
```

My plan is to merge each set of images into PDFs using iTextSharp. When I say set of images, the ones below

```
5093_1.jpg
    5093_2.jpg
    5093_3.jpg
    5093_4.jpg
    5093_5.jpg
```

Will become 5093.pdf and the remaining 5094.pdf.

something like below

```
iTextSharp.text.Document Doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.LETTER);
                    //Store the document on the desktop 
                    string PDFOutput = Path.Combine(PDFFolder, "PDFs", tmp[0] + "_" + tmp[1].Replace(".jpg", "") + ".pdf");
                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, new FileStream(PDFOutput, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read));

                    //Open the PDF for writing 
                    Doc.Open();
                    Doc.NewPage();
                    //Doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Jpeg(new Uri(fi.FullName)));

                    Image jpg = Image.GetInstance(new Uri(fi.FullName));
                    jpg.ScaleToFit(700f, 700f);
                    Doc.Add(jpg);

                    Doc.Close();
```

My question to you folks is, I do i find all the files with 5093 or any number in order so that I can loop through and stich them as PDF.

Thanks a ton for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var path = //your path
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*_*.jpg");
//group only by the bit of the filename before the '_'
var groupedBySamePre_Value = files.GroupBy(p => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(p).Split('_')[0]);
foreach (var group in groupedBySamePre_Value)
{
  //this is a new file group pdf
  foreach (var file in group.OrderBy(p => p))
  {
    //add the file to the pdf
  }
  //end of file group pdf
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But the issue is I want to create multiple PDFs from the above sample. Please see my updates above

Comment: Got ya, so we need to group first on the bit before the underscore. See edits.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can do something like this :

```
Regex regex= new Regex(@"[0-9]+_[0-9].jpg");
var files = Directory.GetFiles(yourPath, "*.jpg").
                  Where(path => regex.IsMatch(path)).ToList();
```

In `regex` I *assume* the following format

```
{at least one number}_{one number}.jpg
```

*Should* work for you.

Comment: Thanks. But the issue is I want to create multiple PDFs from the above sample. Please see my updates above

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion using Array.Sort:

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo=new DirectoryInfo(imageDirPath);
FileInfo fileInfos = dirInfo.GetFiles(*_*.jpg);
Array.Sort(fileInfos, delegate(FileInfo f1, FileInfo f2) {
    return f1.Name.CompareTo(f2.Name);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But the issue is I want to create multiple PDFs from the above sample. Please see my updates above